# How can I persist complex entity with Strategy objects in JPA?

Tags: java, orm, domain-driven-design

I'm using Spring boot JPA to develop a DDD project. I used annotation-based orm to persist the domain objects in DAOs. But now the domain model has become so complex that I consider to perform strategy pattern on Domain Entities.

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
class ComplexEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    // ... other simple fields

    // Example of a strategy object
    // Which deals with complex logics
    private StrategyObject strategyObject;

    // Business methods here
    public void doLogic(OtherEntity other) {
        strategyObject.performOn(other);
        // other logics...
    }
}
```

When I refactor the domain objects like this, the orm becomes such a serious problem that I almost can't deal with. Is there any solutions to persist this kind of complex domain entities?

Comment: What should the StrategyObject look like in the database? Is it a separate table referring to the current or one / multiple values in the current table?

Comment: I want to make it multiple values in the current table, mostly because the strategy object is often taken from the original class which has too many fields and logic. The abstraction of the strategy object is for two reasons: 1. abbreviation of the original class; 2. make it easy to create new classes with only small portion of logic changed while others remain.

Comment: How is StrategyObject annotated?StrategyObject should be annotated with @OneToOne in ComplexEntity, to start with. Please include the StrategyObject code in order to understand what fields need to be persisted

Comment: The StrategyObject is just a wrapper of some fields and methods that maybe reused or expanded by other classes.
For example: Original class may have these things:
    
    class Original { private int a; private String b; public void doSomething() { // Do something with a, b... } 
    class WithStrategy { private StrategyObject so; public void doSomething() { so.doSomething; }

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can not be done with JPA, but Hibernate supports this possibility.

[How to implement custom composite user type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom-cut)

Answer (score 0):

I would create an enum

```
public enum Strategy {

    public abstract StrategyObject getImplementation();

    STRATEGY_1 {
         public StrategyObject getImplementation() {
              return new Strategy1();
         },
    STRATEGY_2 {
         public StrategyObject getImplementation() {
              return new Strategy2();
         }
}
```

and then reference the Strategy enum in your entity:

```
@Entity
class ComplexEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    private Strategy strategy;

    public void doLogic(OtherEntity other) {
        strategy.getImplementation().performOn(other);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I guess I missed the part where the strategies might have a significant amount of configuration that Needs to be stored. But maybe this is a start.

Comment: It is quite suitable and convenient when the strategy don't need to persist any data on the DB, but just pure logic. But if I need to store something in the Strategy Object, the Enum-Solution is not enouph.